# How do I terminate a task upon object deletion? c#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, task

Consider the following class

```
class Melody
{
    public Melody()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>play_melody_in_loop());

    }
}
```

`play_melody_in_loop` plays melody in loop and never completes.

Instances of `Melody` can be collected by GC when they go out of scope. If it happens, I want to stop the playback.

Can I avoid implementing `IDisposable`?

Comment: Implementing IDisposable will not help to catch GC object collection. You will need to add destructor to the Melody class, ~Melody(){ } and stop the task in the destructor

Comment: The GC is nondeterministic. When your object goes out of scope, nothing forces the GC to collect it immediately. This can happen after a long and seemingly random period of time.

Comment: Is there an event for getting out of scope? Is destructor called when it happens?

Comment: No, there is no event. The only way to detect when the object is going to be destroyed by GC is to declare destructor, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx
Note that the destructor is called NOT when the object goes out of scope, but rather whenever GC decides to destroy it. There is no way to detect when the object goes out of scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I needed was `~Melody()`. It doesn't have to be called manually, unlike `Dispose()`.

Thanks to Denis Yarkovoy